# Mysql trigger after update update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below:

```
+---------+------------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| Matchid | Date       | TeamA | TeamB | ScoreA | ScoreB | Winner |
+---------+------------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|       1 | 2014-06-12 | BRA   | CRO   |   null |   null | NULL   |
```

This is a fixture table for a **soccer game**.

After the match is played, I want to update the **ScoreA** and **ScoreB**, then with a trigger after update or even before update, I'll compare the scores and update the winner field accordingly.

When I create update trigger on the table, I am unable to update any of the fields, I read that this is not possible. Then I thought of creating a log of the update, i.e I create a similar table and I wanted to insert both all the new and old records in the log table. 
But this is not possible also.

Is there any way where I can accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: So you want to update the Winner column when the two scores are updated with the team who has the winning score?

Comment: I think you could have the trigger update ALL rows to set the winner, would that be OK?

Comment: @adaam, yes i want a trigger to update the winner column who has winning score.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please elaborate?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the fields in a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_winner BEFORE UPDATE
ON ScoreTable
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.Winner = CASE WHEN NEW.ScoreA IS NULL OR NEW.ScoreB IS NULL THEN NULL
                          WHEN NEW.ScoreA > NEW.ScoreB THEN NEW.TeamA
                          WHEN NEW.ScoreB > NEW.ScoreA THEN NEW.TeamB
                          ELSE "Tie"
                     END
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3747c)